# Is it possible to add new fields to the Summary Link Control

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I am using the PublishingWebControls:SummaryLinkFieldControl and would like to add another field for the Group Description (In addition to the Group Name).

The default field available is the Group Name and Group Items.  I really need an option to to hold the Group Description as well.

Is this possible without customisation?

Answer (score 0):

You'll definitely need to customise to a certain extent!

I know you can create create new item screen by modifying CmsSlwpAddEditLink.aspx (search for it)

Though it seems like what you're after is modifying the creation of the Group.

Rough guess: Figure out which content type the list of fields is based on. Add your field in. Find the .aspx which fires when creating a new group (google it) , drop the field syntax into that and see if that works.

Let us know if you find a solution.